# Grails.View: Embedding pdf from resources

Tags: html, grails, gsp

I have this problem embedding a `.pdf` file located in the folder `web-app\files\[name]` to the `.gsp`.

For example I have this file on this location:

> \web-app\files\tester\test.pdf

I have this code in my `.gsp` having a model entity from its controller: `name:String` and `fileName:String`

```
<embed src="${resources(dir:'files/' + name, file:fileName + '.pdf')">
```

The problem is that I can't have it displayed on the embed folder and when I checked the code, it gives me `src="/ProjectName/static/files/[name]/[fileName].pdf"`

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem here - is the generated URL not resolving the file correctly? Which version of Grails are you using and are you using the resources plugin?

Comment: The link that give you is managed by the resource plugin and it's right, have you tried to open it in the browser to see if you can download the pdf from that link?

Comment: I tried to open the link but it returns an HTML page not the download path of the pdf file.

Comment: need more info. What page you obtain?  Are you testing in a deployed app on in the app runned with "grails run-app"?

Comment: I am currently using Grails 2.0.3 and resources 1.1.6 plugin.

Comment: A 404 Error is return when I open the link. Yes, I am running the application on the development environment via the `run-app` command

Comment: hava you writed the filename and directory name with the right upper and lower case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the resources plugin is configured to manage files in files/name directory

eg:

```
// What URL patterns should be processed by the resources plugin
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']
```

in `Config.groovy`

The `<embed>` tag also takes a mime type attribute which you should set.